# How to export list of hosts in Munin?

Tags: munin

I have inherited a Munin installation and I want to make a list of all the monitored hosts. Is there a command or other way to export a list of all monitored hosts to CSV or XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems rather lame, but I find that

```
grep '^\[' /etc/munin/munin.conf
```

pulls out all the host entries, and nothing much else; you can slice-and-dice it with (eg) `tr` from there.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to look in `<dbdir>/munin-update.stats` (on RHEL and Debian, dbdir is `/var/lib/munin`).  That file contains a line for each host that was checked in the last run.  Each line is of the format:

```
UD|hypervisor;both;esxi1|4.25
```

There are three fields, separated by `|`s.  "UD" stands for something like "update detail"; there's also a "UT" line with the total time it took to update everything, so you should probably `grep '^UD' /var/lib/munin/munin-update.stats`.  The second field is the host and its categories, in the same format that `/etc/munin/munin.conf` has.  The third field is the number of seconds it took to get the host's data.

This approach is a little better than grepping through `/etc/munin/munin.conf` directly for two reasons: Primarily because munin has include directives so it's possible that not all of your hosts are defined directly in the main config file; and secondly just because the file format is simpler, so it's easier to get data out of it.